# How to return selected features with different feature selection models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I use the below function to detect the effect of those feature selection models on my data, it works perfectly.

what I want is to return the name of selected features for each model, is there any convincing way to do that based on my code?

```
def evaluating_model(fs, nm,model,X, y):
    pipe=Pipeline(steps=[('fs',fs),('sc',nm),('model', model)])
    scores = pd.DataFrame( 
        cross_validate(
            pipe,
            X,
            y,
            cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True),
            scoring=["accuracy",'f1','recall','roc_auc','precision'],
            return_train_score=True,
            error_score='raise'
        )
    )
    return scores

featureSelection={  
  "f_classif":SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=10),
  "rfe_RandomForest":RFE(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(), n_features_to_select=10),
  "sf_XGBClassifier":SelectFromModel(XGBClassifier(), max_features=10),
}
for keyFeature,valueFeature in featureSelection.items():
    evaluating_model(valueFeature,anyNormalizer,anyModel,X,y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're doing a 5-fold cross-validation, you have 5 different feature selections (for each selection type). So you want all 5 feature sets returned?

You can add `return_estimator=True` to the `cross_validate`, then extract the selectors' support or feature names out.

Comment: @Ben_Reiniger Thanks for your answer, if it is possible for each round yes. Also, if it is possible please explain your answer with code.

Comment: For example, I can  use `scores["estimator"][0].named_steps["fs"].support_` to predict the selected features of the first cross-validation, Am I correct ? if not please correct me.

Comment: That looks right, yes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer, The complete solution is:

```
def evaluating_model(fs, nm,model,X, y):
    scores = cross_validate(
        Pipeline(steps=[('fs',fs),('sc',nm),('model', model)]),
        X,
        y,
        cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True),
        scoring=["accuracy",'f1','recall','roc_auc','precision'],
        return_train_score=True,
        error_score='raise',
        return_estimator=True
    )

    SelectedFeature=list()
    for value in scores["estimator"]:
        if type(value.named_steps["fs"]).__name__=="RFE":
            SelectedFeature.append(
                X.columns[value.named_steps["fs"].support_].tolist()
            )
        elif type(value.named_steps["fs"]).__name__=="SelectKBest" or type(value.named_steps["fs"]).__name__=="SelectFromModel":
            SelectedFeature.append(
                X.columns[value.named_steps["fs"].get_support()].tolist()
            )

    return scores,SelectedFeature


featureSelection={  
  "f_classif":SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=10),
  "rfe_RandomForest":RFE(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(), n_features_to_select=10),
  "sf_XGBClassifier":SelectFromModel(XGBClassifier(), max_features=10),
}

for keyFeature,valueFeature in featureSelection.items():
    scores,SelectedFeature= evaluating_model(valueFeature,anyNormalizer,anyModel,X,y)
```

Comment: being the first step in the pipeline, I suspect `get_feature_names_out` will work a little more cleanly than `X.columns[...support...]`